# Swap operation error: binding value of type 'const vector<...>' to reference to type 'vector<...>' drops 'const' qualifier

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a class method which returns `const std::vector`:

```cpp
class TriangleMesh
{
public:
    const std::vector<Vec3i>& indices()  const { return m_indices; };
private:
    std::vector<Vec3i> m_indices;
};
```

I'm calling the above method by another struct and doing a `swap` operation:

```cpp
struct Contour3D {
    std::vector<Vec3i> faces3;
    
    // ...
    Contour3D(TriangleMesh &&trmesh);
    
};

Contour3D::Contour3D(TriangleMesh &&trmesh)
{
    faces3.swap(trmesh.indices()); // => error: binding value of type 'const vector<...>' to reference to type 'vector<...>' drops 'const' qualifier
}
```

But I'm receiving this error at `swap` statement:

> error: binding value of type 'const vector<...>' to reference to type 'vector<...>' drops 'const' qualifier

I cannot figure out how to avoid the above error.

#### One option

One option is to avoid `swap` by using a loop. So far I came up with this loop, but I feel like I'm missing something. What I'm missing here:

```cpp
Contour3D::Contour3D(TriangleMesh &&trmesh)
{
    faces3.reserve(trmesh.indices().size());

    std::copy(trmesh.indices().begin(), trmesh.indices().end(),
              std::back_inserter(faces3));
}
```

Comment: You can't involve a `const` into a `swap()` operation, which will try to mutate it. That's why the compiler complains rightfulls.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is the loop fine as a replacement for `swap`?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `faces3 = trmesh.indices();`? Since this is constructor, `faces3` is likely empty anyway. Or better yet, use [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: So, presumably you want to take advantage of the fact `tremesh` is expiring, and just hijack (move) its vector instead of copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Yksisarvinen this statement works fine:

```cpp
faces3 = trmesh.indices();
```